# How to return a Row from Spark UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a use-case where I want to add another entry into a Map object. Here's the setup(with Scala 2.13.13 + Spark 3.3.1):

```scala
    val json =
      """
         [
           {
              "info" : {
                "1234" : {
                  "name": "John Smith",
                  "age": 29,
                  "gender": "male"
                }
              }
           }
         ]
      """

    val personSchema = new StructType()
      .add("name", StringType)
      .add("age", IntegerType)
      .add("gender", StringType)
    val schema = new StructType().add("info", MapType(StringType, personSchema))

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(Seq(json).toDS)
    df.show(false)
```

In this example, I have an `info` object which has a `Map` of `String` to a Person `Struct`. I want to dynamically generate another Person and add it the `info` object. So in JSON, I would end up with:

```json
{
  "info": {
    "1234": {
      "name": "John Smith",
      "age": 29,
      "gender": "male"
    },
    "456": {
      "name": "Robert Jones",
      "age": 35,
      "gender": "male"
    }
  }
}
```

For this, I added the following UDF:

```scala
    val addPersonUDF = udf((infoMap: Map[String, Row]) => {
      infoMap + ("456" -> new GenericRowWithSchema(Array("Robert Jones", 35, "male"), personSchema))
    })
    df.select(col("*"), addPersonUDF(col("info"))).show(false)
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.schemaForTypeUnsupportedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:802)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects$(ScalaReflection.scala:947)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:744)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects$(ScalaReflection.scala:947)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.$anonfun$udf$6(functions.scala:5124)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:5124)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Although both answers below are reasonable solutions to the problem, the root of the problem is you cannot return "rows" from udf's, you need fixed types supported by Spark when encoding.  A row can contain anything as such it's not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Scala case class for the person's data, so that Spark can infer the schema automatically. This way you can avoid using a generic row.

```scala
case class Person(name:String, age: Integer, gender: String)

val schema = new StructType().add("info", 
             ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Map[String,Person]].dataType)
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(Seq(json).toDS)

val addPersonUDF = udf((infoMap: Map[String, Person]) => {
  infoMap + ("456" -> Person("Robert Jones", 35, "male"))
})

df.select(col("*"), addPersonUDF(col("info"))).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|info                            |UDF(info)                                                        |
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|{1234 -> {John Smith, 29, male}}|{1234 -> {John Smith, 29, male}, 456 -> {Robert Jones, 35, male}}|
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple, You don't need any `udf` to do this.

- Unpack `struct` using `*`
- Create new `object` using `named_struct`
- Combine both old & new value using `struct`

```
val fdf = df.selectExpr("""
    struct(
        info.*, 
        named_struct(
            'name','Robert Jones',
            'age', 35,
            'gender','male'
        ) as `456`
    ) as info
""")
```

```
fdf.show(false)

+--------------------------------------------------+
|info                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|{{29, male, John Smith}, {Robert Jones, 35, male}}|
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

```
fdf.toJSON.show(false)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"info":{"1234":{"age":29,"gender":"male","name":"John Smith"},"456":{"name":"Robert Jones","age":35,"gender":"male"}}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Above result is same as your expected output.

```
{
    "info": {
        "1234": {
            "age": 29,
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "John Smith"
        },
        "456": {
            "name": "Robert Jones",
            "age": 35,
            "gender": "male"
        }
    }
}
```